# How to translate this word-play with the word "bargain" into French?

Tags: jeux-de-mots

> Why does this city have to be so cold? I came here to pick up a few **bargains**, but I never **bargained** for this!

I'm trying to translate this colloquial English sentence where the word "[***bargain***](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/bargain)" is used with two different meanings for an amusing effect -- one as a noun, the other as a verb.

I'm wondering how this word-play with the two "bargain"s is effectively rendered into French, ***using two words with identical/similar prononciations, but with two different meanings***.

Without any word-play, I'd say:

> Pourquoi faut-il qu'il fasse si froid dans cette ville? Je suis venu ici pour me faire de l'argent, pas pour me geler sur pied !

Now, with word-play in mind, I'd say something like:

> ... J'y suis venu pour trouver quelques marchandises à prix **cassé**, mais matez-moi ça, ce froid à tout **casser** !
>
> ... J'y suis venu pour trouver quelques marchandises à prix **cassé**, mais comme j'ai hâte de ME **casser** d'ici !
>
> ... J'y suis venu pour acheter quelques marchandises à bon **compte**, je ne **comptais** pas me geler sur pied !

Do any of them work well enough? Ideally, the closer the two words are to one another, the better, to allow for an easier understanding of the word-play at work.

Comment: Your three sentences are fine, just take off **se** in the last one. *Je ne comptais pas geler sur pied*. The phrase exists and is perfectly fine in French, used for plants and for people as well.  Plenty of examples available on the web.

Comment: @Laure Ah, looks like the pronoun was unnecessary. Yes, I used "(me) geler sur pied" to express the idea of "being unable to move from the same spot due to extreme cold". http://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/46251

Comment: Not a very good example the one you found because it does not involve  the freezing aspect. [*Il y a quelques années, j’ai vu de près l’hiver, dans le Jura. Quand on veut éprouver la crainte de geler sur pied, c’est là qu’il faut aller.*](http://fabrice-nicolino.com/?p=203).  Used for plants originally. *Pied* here is - well I don't think there's a single word for it. Depends on the plant ! *un pied de tomate* "tomato plant". *Un pied de vigne* "a vine". *Du raisin gelé sur pied* "grapes frozen on the vine" that 'll give "icewine" (fr. vin de glace, Deu. Eiswein)

Answer (score 6):

Je proposerais :

> Je suis venu pour les prix très bas, je ne pensais pas que la température l'était aussi !

ou

> Je suis venu pour des prix très bas, pas pour des températures très basses !

ou encore

> Je pensais que les réductions concernaient uniquement les prix, pas la température extérieure !

une autre inspirée de la réponse de *MercrediAndThenJedi* qui au lieu de jouer sur la ressemblance des mots joue au moins sur la rime des mots (et accessoirement est très informelle, voire vulgaire...):

> Je suis venu pour m'en mettre plein les fouilles, mais je me gèle surtout les couilles !

Je ne trouve malheureusement pas de jeu de mot similaire à celui de la question...

AJOUT :

Je viens de penser à :

> Je venais ici pour limiter les frais, mais il fait très (trop) frais !

Comment: Une variante: j'étais venu pour me faire des couilles en or, je les ai maintenant toutes petites et toute bleues.

Answer (score 2):

Putain, il fait froid dans c'te ville.  J'étais venu pour faire du lèche-vitrine.  En fait ça va être lèche tomber.  Je rentre.

Comment: J'aime ce jeu de mots, mais ca passe quand-même mieux à l'oral.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see any translation or transposition other than familiar (or even slang), especially if you want to keep the "sound" of the noun/verb. With this in mind, I think of:

1. J'étais venu à l'appel de l'argent, mais je m'les pèle, tout simplement!
2. Je suis venu pour faire du blé à la pelle et tout ce que j'ai gagné c'est que je me pèle...
3. J'étais là pour faire de [l'artiche](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/artiche), mais à la place, je claque des [ratiches](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ratiche)!

Comment: Bravo pour la créativité :-) Ca me donne une autre idée que je vais mettre dans ma réponse tiens :-)

Comment: J'ai évité de mettre ton "ajout" créatif, j'y avais pensé mais ça faisait trop "cru" ;)

Answer (score 2):

A small *contrepèterie* :

> Je m'attendais à frémir de joie devant les soldes, pas à gémir de froid !

Answer (score 0):

"Me geler sur pied" makes no sense in French.

I would say :

- J'y suis venu pour acheter **quelques bonnes affaires, mais ce froid a pas l'air de vouloir négocier !**
- J'y suis venu pour acheter **quelques bonnes affaires, mais ce froid va me coûter cher !**

Comment: Hi. But no word-play in sight! ...

Comment: Ah, sorry I did not understand this. Edited.

Comment: "**se** geler sur pied" might make no sense but *geler sur pied* makes perfect sense, used for plants as well as for people.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens is looking for a way to translate a colloquial from english to french.

For example:

- "Il pleut des hallebardes",
- "Il pleut à verse",
- "Il pleut comme vache qui pisse"

  => "It's raining cats and dogs".

So, in all his three proposals, all are acceptable word-plays.

---

Other possibility (but losing the word-play) :

- "Il gèle à pierre fendre"

  => "It's freezing cold"

Answer (score 0):

If I got the question right then you can say:

> Se geler les pieds / les miches
>
> Se cailler les fesses / les miches / le cul (obviously registre familier)
>
> Se les cailler => J'me les cailles dans ce trou perdu

**Note that maybe some of those are not common throughout any french speaking place, I came from Franche-Comté region in France and they are pretty common here.

(that was for the *se geler sur pied* part which was not correct)

Now a bit about the idiom you want to play around:

> *Je suis venu ici pour me faire de l'argent*,
>
> => mais je n'ai jamais signé pour ça
>
> => mais j'vais rapidement déguerpir / me casser d'ici
>
> => mais je n'ai pas l'intention de moisir ici

If the place is located in the middle of nowhere you can replace *ici* par *ce trou perdu* or *ce coin paumé*.

Or you can use any of the ones of the first part (those consider the fact that the place is cold).

Edit: I did not get the word-play point at first. So it does not answer properly the question.

Answer (score 0):

Autre proposition :

j'étais venu dans cette ville pour tenter de dégeler mes comptes, mais là, je me les gèle à pas cher. ..

Answer (score 0):

Il y a un extrait d'un sketch de Coluche qui pourrait peut-être s'adapter.

> Dans le bois, je te dis pas le temps qu'il fait :
>   T'y vas pour ramasser un bel **engin**, tu reviens avec une belle **angine** !

Pour info, le titre du sketch c'est "La pute".
Ça peut être important si des personnes reconnaissent la référence.